# VBA opening URLs

Tags: excel, vba

Cannot figure out how to get VBA to open a link.

I have an if formula In CN2 which will result in 1 of 5 URLs, the cell is clickable and will direct me to one of these URLS.

I thought perhaps VBA code does not like a formula based URL and turns the result into a hyperlink in CO2, but still I could not get it.

my error with the below code is "cannot open the specified file type"

Can anyone please assist?

```
    Sub OpenURLs()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Range("Co2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim url As String
    url = ActiveSheet.Range("Co2" & i).Value
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink url ' error here

    ' Copy the adjacent value in column CM
    Dim valueToCopy As String
    valueToCopy = ActiveSheet.Range("CM" & i).Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("CM" & i).Copy

    MsgBox "Click OK to continue to the next URL", vbOKOnly
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `Shell "chrome/edge.exe location" "url"`

Comment: What is the value of `url` when you get the error?

Comment: With your code, I get an error if the url does NOT contain "http://" or "https://"

Comment: `url = ActiveSheet.Range("Co2" & i).Value` If i=5 then that's `Range("CO25").Value`   Likewise `ActiveSheet.Range("Co2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` will cause a run-time error.

Answer (score 0):

The bellow code only works IF the cell contains a hyperlink:

```
Sub OpenUrls()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    With sh
        For i = 1 To .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Dim valueToCopy As String
            If .Range("A" & i).Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
                .Range("A" & i).Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=False
                valueToCopy = .Range("B" & i).Value 'Not being used, decided to leave it
                .Range("B" & i).Copy
                MsgBox "Click OK to continue to the next URL", vbOKOnly
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```